# Why in SQL Server 2012 some local groups are missing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

During installation of  SQL Server 2008, the following three local groups are automatically created where `SQLEXPRESS` is the instance name.

```
SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$<computer name>     
SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser$<computer name>  
SQLServerMSSQLUser$<computer name>$SQLEXPRESS
SQLServerSQLAgentUser$<computer name> $SQLEXPRESS
```

However with SQL Server 2012, the last three are missing.

Why did they decide to stop using the local Windows groups? Why does SQL Server 2012 not use local groups anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Because interest is towards managed service accounts or virtual accounts, you can read more about it from below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: The link explained what it is doing, but not why they decided to stop using the local Windows groups.